# Setting petition in my own language

Tags: webform-civicrm, localisation, civipetiton

I'm setting up a petition and would like everything to be in my country's  language (Dutch). I already figured out how to change the wordings in the form itself (first name, last name, e-mail address) but three things remain in English:

- The 'Sign now' button
- The social media sharing option
- The automated thankyou-mail

Any advice on how to change this? It's much appreciated!

Kind thanks!
Pablo

Comment: I see this is tagged as using webform-civicrm (the drupal module) but you don't actually state you are in the question. and your reference to 'social media sharing links' suggests this is in core civicrm. pls clarify and state what cms you are using, since a drupal user might opt to do this in webform

Comment: (note to moderator - i realise my 'rejection' of the edit adding tags was incorrectly thinking they were being removed so pls ignore my rejection of William Mortada's improvement)